# Who taught Ginny Weasley Bat-Bogey hex?

Tags: harry-potter

Nobody in Ginny's family seems to cast [Bat-Bogey hex](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bat-Bogey_Hex) in the books.

Is there a canon mention of who taught her the infamous hex?

Comment: I don't recall any canon mention of who she learnt it from, but it seems likely that it would be one of her brothers (not being mentioned as using it in the books isn't a reliable indication that they didn't know how). Ginny just seems to be particularly adept at it, and it sort of becomes her signature spell (in the same way Harry had Expelliarmus).

Comment: I would like to add it wasn't a 'forbidden' spell, though the teacher on Hoggwarts and Ginny's parents wouldn't have liked it, so she could have read about it in a book from the library, looking for some other spell, or another student could have told her. In short: countless people and books on Hoggwarts could have taught her. It isn't that strange.

Comment: @11684 My recollection is that it's strongly implied she knew the Hex *before* she came to Hogwarts, so a library book and "countless people" seems unlikely.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Perhaps she knew the word to set it off, but she only got a wand when she got to Hogwarts so she couldn't have practiced it. Maybe you're right (I have no idea, I cannot remember any mention of it in the book). In that case, Fred and George are my main suspects.

Comment: @11684 - Hermione practiced spells BEFORE Hogwarts. So did Lily Evans

Comment: @DVK Good point. Though most people find it impressive Ginny is able to cast this hex, which makes it likely they think it is quite advanced magic for her age (something different than the -in Hermione's words - "simple spells" she practiced on the train), making it unlikely she could do it already before her first lesson at Hogwarts'. And remember she had the Trace on her and wasn't allowed to do magic before she got on the train.

Comment: @11684 - I don't read it as they think it is impressive that she *can* cast the hex, just that she is really good at doing it. Kind of like Harry's signature is Expelliarmus.

Answer (score 7):

Well, from what I know, it doesn't mention who taught her it. But like you said it was probably one of her brothers. However, the time it was revealed that she could use it was the 5th book. Percy wasn't around in that book, and he didn't even know where the Order of the Phoenix's headquarters were located due to the Fidelius Charm, so he couldn't have taught it to her.

Considering the nature of the spells, it seems to be slightly malicious and mischievous, it was most likely one of the twins who taught her. This is the best answer I could come up with.

Comment: Are there instances of the brothers teaching her other things? That would help back up this idea.

Comment: @phantom42 On the contrary: it is mentioned after all how suprised the boys were that their sister could fly so well. I'd think it could be something more along the line of Molly teaching her beloved only daughter ways to defend herself (Ginny does hold a special place in her mother's heart after all [*poor Ron, sigh*]).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of other places to learn hexes. They include:

- books
- classes/teachers (especially if Ginny had heard about the hex and asked a teacher)
- other students

That being said, her brothers could also have taught her. There's no canonical evidence of Ginny learning any spell, but she learned them, and it is assumed she learned them from teachers, although I can definitely see Fred and George using the Bat Bogey Hex in front of her, whether they meant for her to learn it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think Fred and George taught her because Fred and George play pranks on everyone.

Maybe she learned it from Tonks or her mother or maybe Hermione or perhaps Luna.

Answer (score 0):

The way the twins speak of it, it seems they don't know the Bat Bogey Hex or at least didn't teach it to her (you would expect a comment on the lines of "*she's as/more dangerous as we are with it*". But she has two other brothers who went to have pretty interesting careers, curse-breaker and dragon handler, so either Bill or Charlie are likely candidates to know that kind of hex and as big brothers, they may have felt the need to teach their little sister to defend herself.